# How to POST Json data without jquery from an action method and read the response

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Clarification: POST requests are between different websites or different controller in the same project.

I want to POST Json data to another action method. I am using Newtonsoft for json serialization, the thing is that in JsonMethod, the field Name comes with null. Am I missing something?

My model:

```
class Person
{
 [JsonProperty("name")]
 public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

The action method that post the json:

```
public ActionResult Method1()
{
  Person p = new Person(){Name = "Test"}
  string urlToRedirect = "..urlRoute../JsonMethod";
  var res = SendRequest(urlToRedirect, p);

  //...do anything with res
}
```

The method that receive the Model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonMethod(Person p)
{
    if(p.Name == "Test")
      return Json("ok");
    else return Json("bad");
}
```

The method that send the request

```
    public async bool SendRequestAsync(string requestUrl, object data) 
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented,
                                 new JsonSerializerSettings
                                 {
                                     ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                                 });

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

            if (request != null)
            {
                request.Accept = "application/json";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "POST";

                using (var stream = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
                {
                    stream.Write(json);
                }

                using (HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    if (response != null && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        throw new Exception(String.Format(
                            "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                            response.StatusCode,
                            response.StatusDescription));

                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        //return true or false depending on the ok
                        return GetResponseModel(responseStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var response = ex.Response;
            Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            //return true or false depending on the ok
            return GetResponseModel(respStream);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why not call JsonMethod directly instead of sending it an http request?

Comment: Indeed. If you're interacting with your own action from another action you control, there's no point in going through all the network and routing infrastructure to access it. Just call it directly. You'd only need to use something like `WebRequest` if you're fetching something from an endpoint external to your project.

Comment: @TWilly, because is not in the same project, actually the post is between different websites

Comment: @chris-pratt read the comment above

Comment: The only thing I see that might be an issue is that you're using async for most things, but namely, you're writing the post data to the stream synchronously. Perhaps try `await stream.WriteAsync(json);` and see if that helps.

Comment: the method was async from the beginning,  just I wanted to be clear with the problem, async is not the mistake on this case, I will edit again the method

Comment: Yep. I actually just ran your code against an API of my own in LINQPad, and with or without async on the write made no difference. I got a response just fine, so the issue seems to be with your actual endpoint. For some reason the modelbinder is failing to bind the posted data properly.

Comment: @chris-pratty any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was the "name" attribute property on person, it must be with capital Letter "Name". Thats why it was coming with null.

[JsonProperty("Name")]